# Deleting table cell causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When deleting table cell using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths I get a crash if I attempt the delete the cell using a swipe gesture to enter editing mode and then hit delete.  If I enter editing mode by toggling an edit/done button then delete cell the table gracefully updates without a problem.

I've also tried using `[table beginUpdates]` & `[table endUpdates]` also without success.
Also `[table reloadData]` works in either case
Also as you can see I've tried `[table reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: indexPath.section] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` with the same crash when entering editing mode with edit/done button.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp = nil;
        switch (indexPath.section)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                temp = self.entireSavedArray;
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                temp = self.entireSavedArray2014;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                temp = self.entireSavedArray2013;
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                temp = self.entireSavedArray2012;
                break;
            } 
            case 4:
            {
                temp = self.entireSavedArray2011;
                break;
            }          
            case 5:
            {
                temp = self.entireSavedArray2010;
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];
        [temp removeObjectAtIndex: ((int)indexPath.row * 11)];

        [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        //[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: indexPath.section] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: It would help if it were possible to make heads or tails of your code.  Comments would be useful.

Comment: The user swipes-to-delete a single row in the table. You then remove 11 objects from a data source array. You then tell the table to delete 1 row. That doesn't add up. You most likely have a mismatch in your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

Comment: I must apologize for my poorly written code.  I created the app in 2009 when learning object oriented programming.  Unfortunately I must now live with my poor design choices.  Each 11 items in the array contains the data for one cell.  I am fairly positive the data is matched correctly - as evidence using an edit/done button works without a problem - vs using a swipe gesture which consistently causes an exception.

Comment: The error is :   *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    // Remove from our mutable array
    [data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Remove from table view
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   }
}
```

Using the code above works for me when deleting a row.

Comment: I find a definite issue when using swipe to delete vs entering edit mode through use of edit/done button.

Comment: When checking the numberOfRowsInSection method:  each section reports the correct numbers of rows and the crash does occur until the method is called for the final section even though the edited section is the first section.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the fact that the swiping gesture puts the table into edit mode without tapping the edit/done button.  This normally would not be a problem, however when the table was not in edit mode I added place holder cells into the table, then adding them back when the done button was pressed. (I changed my data model)  When I originally created the app I had solved that by making the adjustments when the edit/done button was tapped.

**Solution**:  Since the swiping gesture enters edit mode without tapping the edit/done button I needed to make the adjustments in another way.  I did this by using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self makeAdjustments];
}
```

and also making adjustments here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self makeAdjustments];
}
```